# How to convert field to Java properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch-java version 8.10.4 rather than spring-data-elasticsearch.
In my elasticsearch index, the field is underline-word such as "user_id". But in my Java Object, it is "userId". when i get the SearchResponse, the value of "userId" is null, as all the camel-case properties. But the simple property like "id", "model", it works well. How can I resolve it ?

elasticsearch'version is 8.10.4. I tried to use ElasticsearchRestTemplate, unfortunately I failed.
Because of jdk version's incompatible, my jdk version is 1.8; ElasticsearchRestTemplate with elasticsearch 8 needs jdk17.  I can't change jdk version.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

From the scenario you specified , the field in Elasticsearch is mentioned as "user_id," and in the java class it has field named "userId," this will create an issue

Try to use the following to map the field with the attribute of the Java Class

**@Field(name = "user_id", type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String userId;**

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias for this. Not sure how you define your mappings, but it should look something like this

```
{
  "properties": {
    "cabin_temperature_celsius": {
      "type": "alias",
      "path": "cabin_temperature"
    }
  }
}
```